# Overlay overlaps the bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, android-layout, mobile

The parent widget contains a Scaffold and a `bottomNavigationBar`. The widget accepts a body, according to the navigation.

I tried the implementation of flutter itself: Overlay Portal (1 screen);

I tried packages from pub.dev:

```
flutter_portal (2 screen);
dropdown_button 2 (3 screen)
```

Who has encountered this problem and knows where to dig? (I played with context, but without success)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to use the height margins of the navigation bar

I tried to convey a different context

Comment: and what is the problem? what exactly you are trying to do and what should it look like in the end?

Comment: OverlayPortal should not be on top of the `bottomNavigationBar`

Comment: They tend to show the dropdown menu ON TOP of all views, that is, as the topmost view in the stack. this is standard behavior. Alternatively, in the view that contain button, you should make a LOCAL stack and show your drop-down window there, not as a dropdown, but as just a view of the given size and with a scroll inside.